# Corresponding local time of UTC time

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, timestamp, timestamp-with-timezone

I have a set of UTC times:

```
UTC_date
-------------------
2015-10-24 16:38:46
2016-01-19 18:27:00
2016-01-24 16:14:34
2016-02-09 23:05:49
2016-02-11 20:46:26
```

I want to know the corresponding local time of these times, I am in CDT timezone, which should be 5 or 6 hrs behind UTC . 
This is the result I need:

```
UTC_date                         CDT_date
------------------------------------------------
2015-10-24 16:38:46             2015-10-24 11:38:46
2016-01-19 18:27:00             2016-01-19 12:27:00
2016-01-24 16:14:34             2016-01-24 11:14:34
2016-02-09 23:05:49             2016-02-09 18:05:49
2016-02-11 20:46:26             2016-02-11 15:46:26
```

I tried UTC_date::timestamp AT time zone 'CDT', but this will do the opposite way.What PostgreSQL query I could use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `utc_date` is a timestamp without timezone, you can do:

```
select 
    utc_date, 
    utc_date at time zone 'utc' at time zone 'cdt' cdt_date 
from mytable
```

The logic is to first indicate Postgres that the timestamp is in `utc`, and then translate it to the target timezone.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=5fe59715d67000ea06f294eee6555ea7)**:

```
utc_date            | cdt_date           
:------------------ | :------------------
2015-10-24 16:38:46 | 2015-10-24 11:38:46
2016-01-19 18:27:00 | 2016-01-19 13:27:00
2016-01-24 16:14:34 | 2016-01-24 11:14:34
2016-02-09 23:05:49 | 2016-02-09 18:05:49
2016-02-11 20:46:26 | 2016-02-11 15:46:26
```

Comment: Instead of 'cdt' you should use the IANA timezone (aka Olsen) database. In this case either 'America/Chicago' or'US/Central'. The full name automatically adjusts for Day Light Savings time; the abbreviation cdt or cst does not.